# Error in Serializing "c:\path\path" [Errno 13] Permission Denied: C:\\path\\path

Tags: python, robotframework, robotframework-ide

I created one test one test case in Ride using Robot framework. while running am getting the error.

I updated the path of python. I updated the library and Ride. I changed the folder and it didn't work

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     This is a simple test with Robot Framework
Library           SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${SERVER}         http://www.google.com
${BROWSER}        chrome
${DELAY}          0

*** Keywords ***
Open Browser To Login Page
    Open Browser    ${SERVER}    ${BROWSER}
    S
    Maximize Browser Window
    Set Selenium Speed    ${DELAY}
```

Expected Result should allow to run the test case.
Actual result and getting the "Error in Serializing"[image]

Comment: does that file exist? you get a permissions error if you try to open a file that doesn't exist usually...

Comment: "*C:\pythontest\pythontest*" exists and it's a *dir*. Are you trying to save a file with the same name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a issue in the Ride. It looks like once you add a test case as .robot and added a manual script, ride have a issue in saving the file as a Test Suite.

I guess this is the issue you are facing :
[image: Check the image -]

***There are two workarounds to resolve the issue***

**Work around 1**

With out adding the test steps soon after you created the test case,

- Create and save the test case name
- Close Ride
- Re-Open ride (*Now you'll be able to add the test cases and save them with out any issue*)

*Adding Test Suite and Test Case:*
[image: Adding Test Suite and Test Case]
*Editing Test Cases:*
[image: Editing Test Cases]

**Work around 2**

Add the test.robot file manually in your working directly. Then you'll be able to directly edit and save the test cases

*Manual addition of test cases and editing:*
[image]

Hope this helps
Cheers

Answer (score 3):

To install and run Robot framework IDE (RIDE) on windows, run following commands:

1. Install Python [Downloads](https://www.python.org/downloads/)
2. `pip install robotframework`
3. `pip install robotframework-ride`
4. `python -m robotide.__init__`

Comment: On step 3, it would install the latest released version, which is 1.7.3.1. You should install specific version, latest with features and fixes: `pip install robotframework-ride==1.7.4b2`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9776779/vaishali-chaudhari @vaishali chaudhari  Can you explain what this does: python -m robotide.__init__

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4289400/tijnn @tijnn python -m robotide.__init__ execute robotframeframework ide which is  installed in step 3.  It will take a robotide module as script and execute it.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a reported issue [#1869](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/issues/1869) and it was fixed in June. You can try to install the newest Beta version (1.7.4b1d) with:

```
pip install -U robotframework-ride==1.7.4b1
```